# Efficient Amplitude modulation on MCU (C)

Tags: signal-processing, msp430, amplitude, dac

I'm working on an Microcontroller  Synth, but i have ran into a  problem with the volume envelop generation.
I have this code at the moment:
`to_dac =(SinTable[lut_pos] * (volume))>>8;`

It works fine, but the resolution is really bad and i have no idea how to improve it in a way that it can still run fast enough ( as this has to be preformed for every sample)

These are the result I'm getting now :

[The waveform](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B7TersVMKAYAbFpJeTZuU3lHQ1U)

[Here is an MP3 how it sound now: (note: the DAC is on a breadboard and there is no Low pass filter at the output so there is some excess noise)](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B7TersVMKAYAX2hpR2RpSVFmZFU)

I'm using an MSP430 devices(at the moment a MSP430G2553, but if it is really necessary i can use an MSP430F5510 (more memory, faster speed)
I tried too look for examples, but they all use float point variables, sin(); function and others from math.h, but i don't have the luxury of those...

Edit: i was a complete idiot and another piece of code cosed the lower resolution of the amplitude envelope, nonetheless i'm open for other solutions for amplitude modulation.

Comment: No floating point - are you using fixed-point math or simple integers? Should we assume you are using some form of fixed-point with an 8-bit fractional component?

Comment: The oscillator is based on NCO, it has a 32bit phase accumulator witch is truncated down to 8 bits, the position in the look up table (lut_pos).  I have found a better way for amplitude control  of sine waves, Just add two sine waves together with different phase, giving amplitude control with minimal math. like this :'((SinTable[lut_pos[0]] + SinTable[lut_p_phase[0]]))'

Answer (score 0):

I have to see the rest of your code and some of your hardware setup, but I would assume you have a virtual ground that is mid rail?  If so, and your SinTable[] is referenced to the reference ground (i.e. for a 12-bit dac, virtual ground output would be 2048, Vcc would be 4095, and Gnd would be 0, then multiplying by the volume would shift your virtual ground.

Try this..

```
if (SinTable[lut_pos] >= 2048) {
  out = 2048 + (SinTable[lut_pos]-2048)*volume;
} else {
  out = 2048 - (2048-SinTable[lut_pos])*volume;
}
to_dac = out>>8;
```

I'm not sure why you bitshift, but you can save yourself the trouble by scaling the SinTable beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

I look at MSP430G2553 datasheet & have not find any DAC. Are you using external DAC?

Modern MCU have high speed DAC with DMA support. You can fill table in memory (one or more sin periods), than give a command to DMA to send data to ADC.

Thus you will give your CPU much more free time to do other job.